# Python. How i can sorted tuple of dict by value which is list

Tags: python

I have some dicts inside tuples:

```
a = ({'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'F5OZ5311CA', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '2', '1374,13']}},
{'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'FOVY7E395B', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '3', '824,48']}}
{'row_n': 3, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'RH170', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '5', '412,24']}})
```

I need sort this dicts by a['size_measures_multi'][size] and give resul like:

```
a = ({'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'F5OZ5311CA', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '2', '1374,13']}},
{'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'FOVY7E395B', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '3', '824,48']}}
{'row_n': 3, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'RH170', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '5', '412,24']}})
```

I try this

```
for i in a:
    {x: sorted(i['size_measures_multi']['size']) for x in i.keys()}
```

but it give me bad result.

How I can do this. I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Please add the corresponding output for example, it is easier to help you that way.

Comment: Can you give the example output of it being properly sorted?

Comment: @DanielMesejo i add corresponding output

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb i add corresponding output

Comment: I don't see any difference in the input and the  expected output, also the current results would be helpful as well

Comment: So you want to sort by size as if it was a tuple?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes

Comment: Do you want to consider the values inside the list as floating point numbers or strings?

Comment: @DanielMesejo just like string. I will replace the strings to floats before wrte to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the key parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
a = ({'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'F5OZ5311CA', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '2', '1374,13']}},
{'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'FOVY7E395B', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '3', '824,48']}},
{'row_n': 3, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'RH170', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '5', '412,24']}})

result = sorted(a, key=lambda d: tuple(d['size_measures_multi']['size']))

for e in result:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
{'row_n': 1, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'F5OZ5311CA', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '2', '1374,13']}}
{'row_n': 2, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'FOVY7E395B', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '3', '824,48']}}
{'row_n': 3, 'row_section': None, 'TM': 'FORD', 'article': 'RH170', 'description': '', 'size_measures_multi': {'unit': None, 'additional_field': None, 'size': ['1', '5', '412,24']}}
```